# Force Android Webview to use Either Chrome or Firefox

Tags: android, webview

I've discovered that Android webview uses the **default** browser, which sometimes may not be what I need. For instance a user of my app had made snaptube the default browser and could not download a file.

Wy webview just displays a Google Drive file, yet the Download link isn't working with snaptube... or maybe even some other browser.

```
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_view);
    webView =  findViewById(R.id.webViewResults);

    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);

        webView.loadUrl(drive_url + DriveCode + "/view");
```

I just want to ignore / override the default browser.

//===

Afterthought, I'll make the webpage provide a link instead of opening it directly... then I can

```
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
//select my action here
return false;
}
```

Realized the problem was running  window.open automatically-- browser took it to be a popup and blocked it.

Comment: maybe there is some workaround for your case, but you can't pick default engine for `WebView`, it's using default browser set

Answer (score 0):

you can use WebChromeClient as below:

```
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean onJsPrompt(WebView view, String url,
                              String message, String defaultValue, JsPromptResult result) {
        if (callback != null) {
            callback.onResult(message, new PromptResultImpl(result));
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onConsoleMessage(ConsoleMessage consoleMessage) {
        Log.d(JsBridge.TAG, consoleMessage.message());
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: This isn't working, I installed the same snaptube, made it default browser and that's what is loading... can't download a file. wWhen I make Chrome default, problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

You could use custom web view client to override default browser from being opened. Try with below setting to Web View before calling loadUrl() method.

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());

private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried **shouldOverrideUrlLoading** and it isn't called if the link is being opened from javascript-- window.open